# Some framework on top of ASP.NET MVC for easily create backend part of the site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Good day!

For PHP framework CodeIgniter exists 'app-framework' [BackendPro](http://www.kaydoo.co.uk/projects/backendpro):

> What I mean by this is it provides you with functionality to do all the simple repetitive tasks like authentication, permissions and a basic look and feel for your websites control panel. So using your current PHP and CodeIgniter knowledge you can use BackendPro to built a fully working website quickly since you can concentrate on your application instead of the bits to manage the system.

It helps a lot with building quickly backend of the site (grids for entities, common CRUD interface, login\logout etc you know :)). In fact *it is* a stub for a backend. Does something similar for ASP.NET MVC exists?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be interested in this and following articles by Steve Sanderson:

[Scaffold your ASP.NET MVC 3 project with the MvcScaffolding package](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/scaffold-your-aspnet-mvc-3-project-with-the-mvcscaffolding-package/)